# Mapbox animating user location to be more smooth

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mapbox

I'm using Mapbox and instantiating like so:

```
import MapboxGL


class RideViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate, MGLMapViewDelegate{
    @IBOutlet weak var mapViewWrapper: UIView!
    var mapView: MGLMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        // Location manager
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        locationManager.activityType = .Fitness

        // Mapbox
        mapView = MGLMapView(frame: mapViewWrapper.bounds, styleURL: NSURL(string: Mapbox.getTheme()))
        mapView.autoresizingMask = .FlexibleWidth | .FlexibleHeight
    mapView.userTrackingMode = .Follow
    mapView.showsUserLocation = true
    mapView.scrollEnabled = false
    mapView.rotateEnabled = false
    mapView.logoView.hidden = true
    mapView.attributionButton.hidden = true
        // set the map's center coordinate
        mapView.setCenterCoordinate(appleMap.userLocation.coordinate,
            zoomLevel: 12, animated: true)
        mapViewWrapper.addSubview(mapView)

    }

    func locationManager(manager:CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations:[AnyObject]) {
        myLocations.append(locations[0] as! CLLocation)                      
        mapView.setCenterCoordinate(appleMap.userLocation.coordinate, zoomLevel: 16, animated: true)                                                    
    }

}
```

As you can see I have `animated: true` but it's very jittery, any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You're not doing anything wrong, this library is still in beta and they are working on getting smoother user tracking. What's happening is that the user location icon moves into its new position instantly, but the map animates to its new center. This makes it feel rather jumpy. What is needed is to animate the map (and user icon if you want it) based on the speed and course of the user.

However, you are doing it the hard way. Rather than creating your own location manager and setting the map center, you can just set the `mapView.userTrackingMode` to follow the user.

Comment: I tried `userTrackingMode = .Follow` (as seen above) but if I don't do the locationManager it doesn't add the user marker. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Is there something missing?

Answer (score 0):

Distribute your `locationManager` and `mapView` methods throughout the UIview lifecycle methods, for example `viewWillAppear`, `viewDidAppear`, etc.

It should give more time to the system to accommodate the initializations instead of throwing the requests all at once.

Check more about at: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidAppear: